# How to make a SSL Websocket work with Django-channels

Tags: javascript, django, ssl, heroku, websocket

I'm trying to figure out how to get this websocket to work through ssl in https.  Following the django-channels tutorial, I've made a similar web app to the tutorial and deployed it to Heroku.  Heroku's hosted site is secured, so I have my websocket connecting via 'wss://', but this causes errors in the browser console like so:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://asyncdrawshare.herokuapp.com/ws/drawshare/gfdg/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
```

The first error references:

```
var drawSocket = new WebSocket(
    'wss://' + window.location.host +
    '/ws/drawshare/' + roomName + '/');
```

And the second references:

```
drawSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
        'color': drawColor.value,
        'x1': x,
        'y1': y,
        'x2': x + 4 ,
        'y2': y + 4
    }));
```

These are both part of my rooms.html  The first error indicates an un-found url.  This doesn't make sense to me given the routing:

```
# drawshare/routing.py
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ws/drawshare/(?P<room_name>[^/]+)/$', consumers.DrawConsumer),
]
```

It would seem to be this would imply a 404 should not be returned.  The second error seems to be a result of the first as any send invokes another instance of that error.  So if you have any insight into what is going, please let me know.  What is this websocket wanting from me?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find the answer? I'm facing the same issue, can't find anything related.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have been stuck for weeks